# GeoServer- Reload feature type doesn't work

Tags: geoserver, oracle-dbms

I have Oracle database and I had created layer in GeoServer. It had worked good, but when I recreated database with different table structure (some columns dropped, some new added), I've got a problem.

Layer features (table columns) are shown two times, and those columns that have been dropped are also shown. For example, there are two geometry columns, two ID columns, one STATE column (which had been dropped) and so on. Option 'Reload feature type' doesn't work.

How can I clear old columns, and get only new?

EDIT:

I have just tried to clone (copy) this GeoServer instance to another server with another database instance (the same schema). I only changed database parameters and then accessed the layers. Everything is working good. I see columns (features) reflecting current table structure (no duplicates). I also tried to drop one table column and then tried option 'Reload feature type'. It works.

So, what might be the problem?

RESOLVED:

So, I had two database schemas with the same tables (one for testing and one for production purposes). Both schemas were granted dba privileges. Revoking privileges, resolved the problem, but I'm wondering if this is expected behavior.

When creating layer in GeoServer and when choosing table I get all columns from both tables (from both schemas). I think that this should not happen regardless of the db privileges.

Comment: Which GeoServer version are you using?

Comment: GeoServer version 2.6.1

Comment: Do you have feature type caching enabled?

Comment: Feature type cache size value is 0 (default).

Comment: Then I am afraid this is something you need to bring to the GeoServer ML as it is worth to investigate deeper.

Comment: Owwww lifesaver: I had the same problem with duplicate columns appearing, and indeed: it also selected columns from a table with the same name in another schema (from another owner).

Comment: If you want to have the same tables in two different schemas, you'll have to setup two separate store with explicit schema in each, if you have one that does not have the schema specified,  it's known that it won't work: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-2833

Answer (score 1):

Try issuing a full reload in the GeoServer status page

Comment: It doesn't help. The same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I always resaving stores where layer is located, and after that - reload feature type of layer.